# Google Calendar API for Django?

Tags: django, google-api

I was wondering if any one of you have tried implementing Google Calendar API on Django?

any libraries to recommend?

What's your experience in using them?

Comment: I had removed the Calendar module from my gdata folder, since I was getting a name clash with the built-in python calendar. If you do end up using it, you may need to watch out for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just use the Google Calendar API? I don't see a need for another library/wrapper for Django specifically.

Comment: I don't mean to speak for DjangoRocks, but in my case this would be useful as there are things I need to store that are not part of google calendar (custom info specific to my use being pulled from another system).  If I was able to combine the two in django it would allow my view to only have to reference a calendar event once, and the model could take care of keeping google calendar mapped up to the local data.